# Kafka Cassandra sink error while trying to insert data

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka 2.1 and cassandra 3.11.3 ,OS-windows .  I have downloaded the connector from https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/cassandra.html  . I have mentioned the folder containing downloaded jar in plug.path in standalone.properties

the following is my sink properties:

```
 name=cassandra-sink-orders
    connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=caskaf
    connect.cassandra.port=9042
    connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
    connect.cassandra.key.space=springboottest
    connect.cassandra.username=cassandra
    connect.cassandra.password=cassandra
    connect.cassandra.error.policy=NOOP
    connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO student SELECT * FROM caskaf
    connect.progress.enabled=true
```

when i run the connector:

```
.\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties config\cassandra-sink.properties
```

the following is the error i am getting:

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,217] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.MockAdminClient from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
    org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.MockAdminClient
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:404)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:304)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:242)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:183)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.MockAdminClient
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,225] WARN could not get type for name org.scalatest.Assertions from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
    org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.scalatest.Assertions
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:404)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:304)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:242)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:183)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scalatest.Assertions
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,231] WARN could not get type for name org.easymock.EasyMockSupport from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
    org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.easymock.EasyMockSupport
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:404)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:304)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:242)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:183)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.easymock.EasyMockSupport
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,235] WARN could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
    org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:404)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:304)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:242)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:183)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,248] WARN could not get type for name jline.Completor from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
    org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name jline.Completor
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
            at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:404)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:304)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:242)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:183)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.Completor
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
            at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,445] WARN The configuration 'offset.flush.interval.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,445] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,447] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.file.filename' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,447] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,447] WARN The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,447] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:25,447] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
    Jun 02, 2020 5:44:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
    WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource will be ignored.
    Jun 02, 2020 5:44:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
    WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource will be ignored.
    Jun 02, 2020 5:44:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
    WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource will be ignored.
    Jun 02, 2020 5:44:27 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
    WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.     
    [2020-06-02 17:44:27,753] WARN Found Netty's native epoll transport, but not running on linux-based operating system. Using NIO instead. (com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil)
    [2020-06-02 17:44:30,101] WARN You listed localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 in your contact points, but it wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup (com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the kafka-connect version you are running 2.1 also? Can you also post the classpath jars that are loaded during connect startup?

During the first lines of the connect's startup you should see something this

```
...
[2020-06-02 19:38:39,242] INFO WorkerInfo values: 
    jvm.args = -Xms256M, -Xmx2G, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties
    jvm.spec = Azul Systems, Inc., OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_212, 25.212-b04
    jvm.classpath = /etc/kafka-connect/jars/*: ...
    ...
    *:/usr/share/java/support-metrics-client/*...
    ...
```

Also, is there a url with the specific kafka-connect archive in order to replicate this?